# Is there any way to program hover over behavior for files shown in windows explorer?

Tags: python, winapi, user-interface

I want to pop up my own label when mouse hovers over a directory/file in windows explorer. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by creating a Shell Extension of the Infotip handler variety.

These two URLs will help you, at least if you can map the Win32 C++ stuff to Python. (Sorry, I don't know much about Python to know how easy that part is.)

- [MSDN: Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [CodeProject: The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx)